# Connecting local server remotely outside network

Tags: ssh, server

so i have already connecting a server (using ssh local ip) and it works just fine but when i'm outside of the network, i can't use the server anymore. My question is how can i use the server outside the network? i want to use my college server, they just gave me local ip, username, and password. Is there any way to connect it outside the network with those resources only?

i have already search the answer, the answer is port forwarding. But i don't have an access to the router. Is there any way other than port forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

Your college almost certainly does not want you to be able to access the internal server directly from the Internet, for security reasons.

However, if there is a server that they do allow you to access then you may be able to use that as a stepping stone into the network.

```
home$ ssh user@external_server
external_server$ ssh user@internal_server
internal_server$ _
```

If that works then you can shortcut the process with the `-J` "jump host" option:

```
home$ ssh -J external_server user@internal_server
internal_server$ _
```